# Wordwrap in Jide's CodeEditor?

Tags: java, word-wrap, jide

I searched for word wrap and line wrap in jide's CodeEditor and nothing found, is it possible to wrap contents around current viewport?

Thank you,
Mika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIDE Code Editor doesn't support line wrapping. The reason is, as its name indicates, it is for source code editing purpose. I haven't seen any code editors in the major IDEs that support line wrapping.

Comment: Xcode does it. Sublime Text 2 does it. Are you sure you even had your eyes open?